# UiTextField and resignFirstResponder

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, first-responder

I have a weird setup.

I have a `View` called **View1** and a `ViewController` call **viewController1**

in `IB`, **View1** is a child of the **ViewController1**.

Inside **View1**, I created using code a `UITextField` and added as a subview.

In my `Viewcontroller`, I have `viewController1 : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>`

Now.. I would like to resign the keyboard when the text field within **View1** gets the "Done" button in the keyboard so I have

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)TEXTFIELD {
    [TEXTFIELD resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Now the question is, how do I make the connection between TEXTFIELD (defined in my viewcontroller) and the textfield defined in my View?

Do I have to do something in interfaceBuilder?

maybe I am totally off here....

Some hints greatly appreciated

Answer (score 14):

Kendall is right. You need to set your viewController1 as the delegate of your text field.

In your comment above, I think you're misunderstanding the textFieldShouldReturn method. The UITextField* is passed in as a parameter to this method, so that the delegate can see which field wants to return, and decide whether to allow it to. In your case, you only have one textfield, so just resign first responder and return YES (my code is below).

Try putting a breakpoint on this textFieldShouldReturn function. Is it getting called?

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)aTextField
{
    [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I can't for the life of me work out why this doesn't work for me.

Comment: @CVertex probably because you've not set up the `UITextField` delegate.

Answer (score 7):

Connect the delegate property of the text field to your view controller in IB (should be File's Owner for that view).  Also note in the view controller header that you conform to the  protocol.

Or you can just set the texfield.delegate property to self in the viewDidLoad method of the view controller.

Comment: I now have my View1 's delegate hooked up to the FileOwner within IB
STill doesnt work :(

In the method 
(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)returnTextField.
The returnTextField should match the textfield in the view.
I just dont see where I can make that connection.

Comment: It's the delegate, that's the only connection you can make.  As noted, make sure the view controller header implements the UITextFieldDelegate protocol.