# iOS - Dismiss keyboard when touching outside of UITextField

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uikit

I'm wondering how to make the keyboard disappear when the user touches outside of a `UITextField`.

Comment: Dmitry had the correct answer. This is not a gesture problem - its a problem of resigning the first responder. Dmirty's answer is also the solution recommended by Mark, Nutting and LeMarche in [Beginning iOS 4 Development](http://www.amazon.com/dp/143023024X), Chapter 4, page 83.

Answer (score 791, accepted):

You'll need to add an `UITapGestureRecogniser` and assign it to the view, and then call resign first responder on the `UITextField` on it's selector.

The code:

**In viewDidLoad**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

**In dismissKeyboard:**

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard 
{
    [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

(Where `aTextField` is the textfield that is responsible for the keyboard)

**Swift 3** version looks like that

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard (_:)))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

**For dismissKeyboard**

```
@objc func dismissKeyboard (_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    aTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: This works but what it does is it also disables or makes navigation bar buttons as unclickable. So is there a work around for this?

Comment: This doesn't work when the user do other gesture like scrolling. A better solution is to use hitTest:withEvent:

Comment: This is not good if you need to touch the "X" icon on the right of the textfield to clean the field. If you enable the gesture recognizer, you need to keep it enable while the focus is on the textField and therefore you can't touch such "X" icon.

Comment: Try this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456120/hiding-the-keyboard-when-losing-focus-on-a-uitextview

Comment: this is worked for me but i have one button with checkbox functionality but its not working as a checkbox after applying this

Comment: Need to be added:
`- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textFieldToResign = textField;
}`
this will help to resign selected textField

Comment: I think better than `[aTextField resignFirstResponder]` would be `[self.view endEditing:YES];` it do not need a reference to the text field and will work for multiple textfields

Comment: So without having to define any methods, a one-liner would be: `[self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.view action:@selector(endEditing:)]];`

Comment: @ParthBhatt I added `[tap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];` per @qiaoyi 's answer; I had an issue with a table not responding to row selections. 5 years later, I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Swift one-liner:     `self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:))))`

Comment: Be aware this will also prevent selection of rows in a static tableview

Comment: FYI: about `endEditing` – If the force parameter is set to true, the text field is never even asked to resign. So better to: `view.endEditing(false)`

Comment: Swift `addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(endEditing(_:))))`

Comment: How about if there is a UIButton, I want to hide the keyboard, and the UIButton touch action also works when the user touching the button? The solution doesn't work in that scenario.

Comment: This solution not work  along view inside subview.... need UITapGestureRecognizer object to add "cancelsTouchesInView " = false   look my better solution look my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306240/ios-dismiss-keyboard-when-touching-outside-of-uitextfield/64335128#64335128

Answer (score 181):

I mashed up a few answers.

Use an ivar that gets initialized during `viewDidLoad:`

```
UIGestureRecognizer *tapper;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    tapper.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapper];
}
```

Dismiss what ever is currently editing:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, it works on UITableView!! it save my day!
As a side note I will use [UITextField resignFirstResponder] instead of [UIView endEditing:] because I have more UITextField and endEditing gives a wrong scrolling position even if the new UITextField is visible.

Comment: Dead wrong because the UITapGestureRecognizer is never added to to the view!

Comment: What is the purpose of cancelsTouchesInView here?

Comment: If you don't add cancelsTouchesInView = false here, then you won't be able to select other types of items in your view.  Your taps will be intercepted by the gestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 106):

Check this, this would be the easiest way to do that,

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
      [self.view endEditing:YES];// this will do the trick
}
```

Or

This library will handle including scrollbar auto scrolling, tap space to hide the keyboard, etc...

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: @Ramesh yes it does, but not in this way. you need to create a subclass from UITableView and inside that class implement the touchesBegan method and then call endEditing method. it works! don't forget to set the class for your table in the nib with newly created class.

Comment: It doesn't hide keyboard when user touches on other controls on view. Ex: I have a UIButton and UITextField on UIView. I tap on UITextField, then tap on the button, the keyboard does not hide in this case.

Comment: @JacobDam You're right.  The goal is to resignfirstresponder to hide the keyboard if *anything* happens outside of aTextField.

Answer (score 90):

I see that some people are having issues using the `UITapGestureRecognizer` method. The easiest way that I've accomplished this functionality while still leaving my existing button's tap behavior intact is adding only one line to @Jensen2k 's answer:

```
[tap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
```

This allowed my existing buttons to still work without using @Dmitry Sitnikov 's method.

Read about that `property` here (search for `CancelsTouchesInView`): [UIGestureRecognizer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

I'm not sure how it would work with scrollbars, as I see some had issues with, but hopefully someone else might run into the same scenario I had.

Comment: I would also like to add, for those having a background image at the back of the view using `UIImageView`, add `[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];` and you "click through" it, which make this method work.

Answer (score 56):

It is better to make your `UIView` an instance of `UIControl` (in interface builder) and then connect their `TouchUpInside` event to `dismissKeyboard` method. This `IBAction` method will look like:

```
- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender {
    [aTextBox resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me and other solutions did not. (`UITapGestureRecognizer` interfered with tapping on buttons inside the view). `touchesEnded` did not work because there was a `UIScrollView` messing with the responder chain.)

Comment: If there are buttons inside the view and tapping them should dismiss the keyboard, you also have to connect their Touch Down event to `-dismissKeyboard`.

Comment: This works great, but has to be added to anything you want to have dismiss the keyboard.  Is there a way to automatically have a text box resign first responder on tapping anything else?

Comment: @IsaacOveracker: see my answer below.

Comment: You shouldn't need to make UIView a UIControl. Make sure the UIView has User Interaction Enabled.

Comment: This method is recommended by Jeff LeMarch in [Beginning iOS 4 Development](http://www.amazon.com/dp/143023024X) (et al). Chapter 4, page 83.

Comment: @SofiSoftwareLLC Your suggestion didn't work for me. I had to make it a UIControl even when User Interaction Enabled was checked.

Comment: Using a StoryBoard I changed UIView to UIControl (where I would have selected a UIView subclass had I made one). It works well. I haven't run into any issues. iOS8.

Answer (score 49):

**Swift 4**

Setup your `UIViewController` with this extension method once e.g in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setupHideKeyboardOnTap()
}
```

and the keyboard will be dismissed even by tapping on the `NavigationBar`.

```
import UIKit
extension UIViewController {
    /// Call this once to dismiss open keyboards by tapping anywhere in the view controller
    func setupHideKeyboardOnTap() {
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.endEditingRecognizer())
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addGestureRecognizer(self.endEditingRecognizer())
    }

    /// Dismisses the keyboard from self.view
    private func endEditingRecognizer() -> UIGestureRecognizer {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(self.view.endEditing(_:)))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        return tap
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro, you nailed it !! This answer is perfect and works really great, thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks!. It is save my day

Answer (score 28):

Swift version, this works in combination with other elements (like a `UIButton` or another `UITextField`):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapper = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(endEditing))
    tapper.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapper)
}
```

Comment: target should be `self` rather than `self.view`

Comment: target should be self.view. Otherwise, above code will crash.

Comment: `canclesTouchesInView` is a handy property to use. Thanks.

Comment: Old habits die hard. What's that semicolon doing here ? ;)

Comment: @AlexandreG. Indeed, especially since I'm generally coding `c#`. FYI That semicolon is syntax-allowed, it's just not necessary.

Comment: If your action selector method is in a view swift file for the current VC then yes, target should be self.view. Most times the action selector method will be in the VC itself, so target would just be self. Hope that helps someone. :)

Answer (score 17):

How about this: I know this is an old post. It might help someone :)

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
    NSArray *subviews = [self.view subviews];
    for (id objects in subviews) {
        if ([objects isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *theTextField = objects;
            if ([objects isFirstResponder]) {
                [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't check for UITextField so it works for any input type. Not seeing any problem.

Answer (score 17):

This is a good generic solution:

Objective-C:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];    
}
```

Swift:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Based on @icodebuster solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18756253/417652

Answer (score 15):

Swift 4 oneliner

```
view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:))))
```

Comment: Nice code, but this one disables the delete function (-)

Comment: You are a genius!

Answer (score 10):

I think the easiest (and best) way to do this is to subclass your global view and use `hitTest:withEvent` method to listen to any touch. Touches on keyboard aren't registered, so hitTest:withEvent is only called when you *touch/scroll/swipe/pinch...* somewhere else, then call `[self endEditing:YES]`.

This is better than using `touchesBegan` because `touchesBegan` are not called if you click on a button on top of the view. It is better than `UITapGestureRecognizer` which can't recognize a scrolling gesture for example. It is also better than using a dim screen because in a complexe and dynamic user interface, you can't put dim screen everywhere. Moreover, it doesn't block other actions, you don't need to tap twice to select a button outside (like in the case of a `UIPopover`).

Also, it's better than calling `[textField resignFirstResponder]`, because you may have many text fields on screen, so this works for all of them.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to interfere with UISearchBar's 'X' to clear text.

Comment: there are some problems with this approach. for example, you cant scroll a scrollview without loosing focus on your textfield. not advisable for more complex scenarios... personally, i prefer the uicontrol-version from Dmitry, maybe extended by the coment from Sofi Software.

Comment: One example of the scrolling is in the email app, when you are typing into the search bar and then scroll the mail list, the keyboard is dismissed.

Comment: Its the best approach and had done to my other projects.

Answer (score 9):

This must be the easiest way to hide your keyboard by touching outside :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];    
}
```

(from [How to dismiss keyboard when user tap other area outside textfield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756196/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-when-user-tap-other-area-outside-textfield))

Answer (score 7):

If the view is embedded at all in a `UIScrollView` then you can use the following:

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
```

The former will animate the keyboard off screen when the table view is scrolled and the later will hide the keyboard like the stock Messages app.

> Note that these are are available on iOS 7.0 or above.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using the Storyboard in XCode 6 and above:

### Create the action to hide the keyboard

Add this to the header file of the class used by your ViewController:

```
@interface TimeDelayViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

- (IBAction)dissmissKeyboardOnTap:(id)sender;

@end
```

Then add this to the implementation file of the same ViewController:

```
- (IBAction)dissmissKeyboardOnTap:(id)sender{
    [[self view]endEditing:YES];
}
```

This will now be one of the 'Received Actions' for your storyboard scene (i.e. ViewController):

[image]

### Hook up the action to the user event

Now you need to hook up this action to the user gesture of touching off the keyboard.

**Important - You need to convert the 'UIView' that's contained in your storyboard to a UIControl**, so it can receive events. Select the view from your View Controller Scene hierarchy:

[image]

...and change its class:

[image]

Now drag from the small circle next to the 'received action' for your scene, onto an 'empty' part of your scene (actually you're dragging the 'Received Action' to the UIControl). You'll be shown a selection of events that you can hook up your action to:

[image]

Select the 'touch up inside' option. You've now hooked the IBAction you created to a user action of touching off the keyboard. When the user taps off the keyboard, it will now be hidden.

*(NOTE: To hook the action to the event, you can also drag from the received action directly onto the UIControl in your View Controllers hierarchy. It's displayed as 'Control' in the hierarchy.)*

Comment: Thanks for the solution and detailed explanation. Really helpful to me.

Answer (score 5):

If I got you right you want to resign keyboard wile tapping on outSide of `textfield` but you don't have reference of your `textfield`.

Try this;

- Take global textField, lets call it `reftextField`
- Now in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` set referenced text field to

  ```
  - (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
      reftextField = textField;
  }
  ```
- Now you can happily use on any button clock, (adding a transparent button on begin editing recomended)

  ```
  - (void)dismissKeyboard {
        [reftextField resignFirstResponder];
  }
  ```
- Or for resigning done button try this.

  ```
  //for resigning on done button    
  - (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
      [textField resignFirstResponder];
      return YES;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 5):

In swift 5 You can use following code to dismiss keyboard  outside textfield

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // ... code

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)  
}

@objc func dismissKeyboard(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: If your view also has `tableViews` or `collectionViews` in it, include the following as part of the tapGesture configuration: `tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false`

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to the list here my version of how to dismiss a keyboard on outside touch.

viewDidLoad:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Anywhere:

```
-(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    [textFieldName resignFirstResponder];
    puts("Dismissed the keyboard");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Objective-C:**

Add this code in your **ViewController.m** file :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

**Swift:**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Sweeet! I love this one answer. Precise and as small as possible. Why bother setting up gesture recognizers and all other boilerplate? this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of great answers here about using `UITapGestureRecognizer`--all of which break `UITextField`'s clear (X) button. The solution is to suppress the gesture recognizer via its delegate:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    BOOL touchViewIsButton = [touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]];
    BOOL touchSuperviewIsTextField = [[touch.view superview] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]];
    return !(touchViewIsButton && touchSuperviewIsTextField);
}
```

It's not the most robust solution but it works for me.

Comment: Exactly, All above things fails if i tap in the same textfield.
It resigns even the textfield is my responder. and it also closes keyboard on tapping clear button inside the textField

Comment: I would simplify it by just doing the test for button: `return !touchViewIsButton`. I guess any other buttons that need to dismiss the keyboard should do it in their actions. In addition TouchUpInside might not get called when the layout changes on keyboard dismissal.

Answer (score 3):

You can create category for the UiView and override the touchesBegan meathod as follows.

It is working fine for me.And it is centralize solution for this problem.

```
#import "UIView+Keyboard.h"
@implementation UIView(Keyboard)

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.window endEditing:true];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift version of @Jensen2k's answer:

```
let gestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

func dismissKeyboard() {
    aTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

One liner

```
self.view.addTapGesture(UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: "endEditing:"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried many of the responses here and had no luck.  My tap gesture recognizer was always causing my `UIButtons` to not respond when tapped, even when I set the `cancelsTouchesInView` property of the gesture recognizer to NO.

This is what eventually solved the issue:

Have an ivar:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *_keyboardDismissGestureRecognizer;
```

When a text field begins editing, set the gesture recognizer:

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(_keyboardDismissGestureRecognizer == nil)
    {
        _keyboardDismissGestureRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self
                                       action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)] autorelease];
        _keyboardDismissGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_keyboardDismissGestureRecognizer];
    }
}
```

Then the trick is in how you set up the `dismissKeyboard` method:

```
- (void) dismissKeyboard
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissKeyboardSelector) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
}

- (void) dismissKeyboardSelector
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:_keyboardDismissGestureRecognizer];
    _keyboardDismissGestureRecognizer = nil;
}
```

I guess there's just something about getting the `dismissKeyboardSelector` execution out of the touch handling execution stack...

Answer (score 2):

I used Barry example for my new development. It worked great! but i had to include a slightly change, required to dismiss the keyboard only for the textfield being edited.

So, I added to Barry example the following:

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    _textBeingEdited = textField;
}
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    _textBeingEdited = nil;
}
```

Also, I changed hideKeyboard method as follows:

```
- (IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender
{
    // Just call resignFirstResponder on all UITextFields and UITextViews in this VC
    // Why? Because it works and checking which one was last active gets messy.
    //UITextField * tf = (UITextField *) sender;
    [_textBeingEdited resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the most easiest and shortest way is to add this code to your `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                     initWithTarget:self.view
                                     action:@selector(endEditing:)]];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first{
     view.endEditing(true)

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Send message `resignFirstResponder` to the textfiled that put it there. Please [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684579/uitextfield-and-resignfirstresponder) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

### This works

In this example, aTextField is the only UITextField.... If there are others or UITextViews, there's a tiny bit more to do.

```c
// YourViewController.h
// ...
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController /* some subclass of UIViewController */ <UITextFieldDelegate> // <-- add this protocol
// ...
@end

// YourViewController.m

@interface YourViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapRecognizer;
@end
// ...

@implementation
@synthesize singleTapRecognizer = _singleTapRecognizer;
// ...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // your other init code here
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.singleTapRecognizer];

{

- (UITapGestureRecognizer *)singleTapRecognizer
{
    if (nil == _singleTapRecognizer) {
        _singleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapToDismissKeyboard:)];
        _singleTapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; // absolutely required, otherwise "tap" eats events.
    }
    return _singleTapRecognizer;
}

// Something inside this VC's view was tapped (except the navbar/toolbar)
- (void)singleTapToDismissKeyboard:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"singleTap");
    [self hideKeyboard:sender];
}

// When the "Return" key is pressed on the on-screen keyboard, hide the keyboard.
// for protocol UITextFieldDelegate
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField
{
    NSLog(@"Return pressed");
    [self hideKeyboard:textField];
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender
{
    // Just call resignFirstResponder on all UITextFields and UITextViews in this VC
    // Why? Because it works and checking which one was last active gets messy.
    [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"keyboard hidden");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                          initWithTarget:self
                                                          action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [singleTapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [singleTapGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:singleTapGestureRecognizer];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -40) animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use UITapGestureRecongnizer method for dismissing keyboard  by clicking outside of UITextField. By using this method whenever user will click outside of UITextField then keyboard will get dismiss. Below is the code snippet for using it.

```objc
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissk)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];


//Method
- (void) dismissk
{
    [abctextfield resignFirstResponder];
    [deftextfield resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, there can be use **ScrollView** and added to `TextField` in ScrollView and I want Tap the `ScrollView` and View then Dismiss the Keyboard. I tried to create sample code just in case. Like this,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    func tap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Your Storyboard Look at that Just Like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Set text fields delegate in view did load:

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() 
  {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.userText.delegate = self
  }
  ```
- Add this Function:

  ```
  func textFieldShouldReturn(userText: UITextField!) -> Bool 
  {
   userText.resignFirstResponder()
   return true;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

For those struggling with this in Swift. This is the accepted answer by Jensen2k but in Swift.

**Swift 2.3**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //.....

        let viewTapGestureRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleViewTap(_:)))
        //this line is important
        viewTapGestureRec.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(viewTapGestureRec)

         //.....
    }

    func handleViewTap(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        myTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing to important...

adding gesture recognize to view can subview override it..
So only one action is performed..
If you want to perform recognize multiple action through superview and subview...
You have to  use

```
 tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Full code is below:

```
 let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.superViewClicked))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tap.delegate = self
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)




  @objc func superViewClicked(){
        
        self.searchTF.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

> What is best solution for dissmis soft keyboard on outside click?

I will  explain for one condition:

Think about it : You have UISearchBar on the top,
then tableview with header added!

Solution is simple:

1. track soft keyboard is open or dismiss
2. Add gesture recognize to header view
3. implement delegate of table view didSelectRowAt

Full code:

```
   var isSoftKeyboardActive = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    
        var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tableHeaderClick))
            tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            tap.delegate = self
            tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
            self.headerOfTableView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    
    }
    
          override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
                 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillDisappear), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
                  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillAppear), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
              }
              
              override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
                  super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
                  NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
              }
        


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          if isSoftKeyboardActive == true{
               
               self.searchTF.resignFirstResponder()
           }else{
           
               selectedRow = indexPath.row
               performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueWebview", sender: self)
               
           }
    }
    


 
    @objc func tableHeaderClick(){
         
        self.searchTF.resignFirstResponder()
    
     }
    
    
    
  @objc func keyboardWillAppear() {

        
        isSoftKeyboardActive = true
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillDisappear() {
        
        isSoftKeyboardActive = false
        
    }
```

How is it work:

1. If soft keyboard is open and user click header soft keyboard close
2. If soft keyboard is open and user click cell, keyboard close and no perform cell click

Answer (score 0):

just use this code in your .m file it will resign the textfield when user tap outside of the textfield.

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  [textfield resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.view.endEditing(true)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding more detail to answer

Answer (score 0):

So I just had to solve this very problem, and none of the previous answers worked for me out of the box. My situation: a `UISearchBar`, plus a number of other controls on the screen. I want for a tap outside of the search bar to dismiss the keyboard, but **not** propagate to any of the other controls. When the keyboard is hidden, I want all the controls to work.

What I did:

1) Implement a custom touch handler in my view controller.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    if searchBar.isFirstResponder()
    {
        // This causes the first responder, whoever it is, to resign first responder, and hide the keyboard.
        // We also "eat" the touch here and not allow it to propagate further.
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    else
    {
        // OK to propagate the touch
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    }
}
```

2) Added a couple of delegate methods (mine are for the UISearchBar, but there are similar ones for UITextField). `controlContainerView` in the code below is a UIView that has a bunch of buttons in it. Remember that setting `userInteractionEnabled` on a superview disables all its subviews.

```
 func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar)
 {
     controlContainerView.userInteractionEnabled = false
     someButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
 }

 func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar)
 {
     searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    // Done editing: enable the other controls again.

    controlContainerView.userInteractionEnabled = false
    someButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad
swift 4.2
The code like this

```
let viewTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(viewTap)
@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For collection view:

```
// the keyboard follows the dragging touch off screen, and may be pulled upward again to cancel the dismiss
collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
// dismisses the keyboard when a drag begins
collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```