# Hiding in the iOS keyboard when user clicks outside of a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, html

I'm attempting to hide the iPad soft keyboard when the user clicks outside a text field.

Specifically somewhere on the form or body that contains no other elements.

Using jquery, jquery mobile, and html5.

Comment: have you tried calling textfield.blur()? Of course you have to fetch the click before in any way.

Comment: keyboard should hide on the blur event of the input..if not the problem is elsewhere. show your code

Comment: Right now using an Android tablet it functions perfectly.  The user clicks outside the textbox, and the keyboard will collapse.

I only have the code below, everything else I've tried has failed.

var hideKeyboard = function() {
    document.activeElement.blur();
    $("input").blur();
};

This is so the textbox will blur so the keyboard closes, if the user clicks any other element like radio buttons etc... 

Is there a way to have this work with the form or body as well?

I'm a C programmer by trade, and javascript makes me want to rip my hair out.

Comment: do you have more then one textfield?

Comment: setTimeout(function(){
    $('Wrappingdiv').click(function(){console.log('!')})
  },0)

Comment: I solved this problem with the line of code from the previous comment.

Comment: Here is solution for this ,it worked for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306240/iphone-dismiss-keyboard-when-touching-outside-of-textfield

Answer (score 11):

```
document.activeElement.blur();
```

Comment: Can anyone tell me where to add this code as I am trying to do the same but I am not able to attach it properly. Currently I am trying to attach it on window object. But once I run it, it just stops opening the keypad. Need to know whom to attach it.

Comment: try to put the code on `$(document).click(function() { });`

Answer (score 3):

using mattwindwer's solution (but with more details):

```
$(document).click(function() {
    document.activeElement.blur();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `focus()` method on a button (even hidden buttons) hides the keyboard. I have used this in my ipad web app.

You can add a click listener to body and using target property of the event, you can determine when to hide the keyboard.