# Dismissing keyboard on tapping outside the table

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikeyboard

Before you dismiss my question as being a duplicate of this one: [iphone, dismiss keyboard when touching outside of UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306240/iphone-dismiss-keyboard-when-touching-outside-of-textfield)
The issue for me is that my textfield is part of my prototype cell which has its own subclass of uitableview cell and so I'm not sure how to reference the textfield when trying to resign the first responder. SO, I can't just do this:

```
 -(void)dismissKeyboard {
   [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

How would I get across this situation?

Thanks

Comment: You can if you add a `UITextField` property to your `UITableViewCell` subclass and wire this property up to the text field you have created in your prototype.

Comment: @Scott, I have already done that. How would I reference it, since this dismiss keyboard is part of my view controller class, not the uitableviewcell subclass.

Comment: Check this response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15160559/656600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, it's very useful:

```
-(void)touchesBegan :(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

    [aTextField resignFirstResponder];

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

}
```

Comment: touchesBegan doesn't work for me because my table view is inside a scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

I think dismissing keyboard on tapping outside the table view cell is not good. User may accidently touching outside or he can scroll while entering text right?.  You can use the `UITextFieldDelegate`  to dissmiss keyboard

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
 {
   [textField resignFirstResponder]
 }
```

Comment: Anil please read my question carefully. I'm trying to follow these instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306240/iphone-dismiss-keyboard-when-touching-outside-of-textfield

Comment: Hmm.. maybe but I need to do it based on my design. Can u help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you want to resign keyboard wile tapping on outSide of `textfield` but you don't have reference of your `textfield`.

Try this;

- Take global textField, lets call it `reftextField`
- Now in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` set referenced text field to

  ```
  - (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
      reftextField = textField;
  }
  ```
- Now you can happily use on any button clock, (adding a transparent button on begin editing recomended)

  ```
  - (void)dismissKeyboard {
        [reftextField resignFirstResponder];
  }
  ```
- Or for resigning done button try this.

  ```
  //for resigning on done button    
  - (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
      [textField resignFirstResponder];
      return YES;
  }
  ```