# How to hide the keyboard when touching screen (search bar)

Tags: ios, keyboard, hide, searchbar

The keyboard hides when I click search or when I click on cancel.
But I want also that the keyboard hides when I click somewhere on the screen.
I found several tutorials for the textfield, but we are using the search bar.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this answer by Jensen2k: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306240/iphone-dismiss-keyboard-when-touching-outside-of-textfield

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah i tried that one too. Problem is that i don't have a textfield where the keyboard is attached too. The search bar calls the keyboard so i have to resign it with the search bar. Do you know another solution? Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try This

in your .h file add UISearchBar

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

in your .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}


- (void) dismissKeyboard
{
    // add self
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Tried it first part didn't give any errors, second part says again: 'Unkown receiver 'searchBar'; did you mean UISearchBar?' Thanks for the help. I think this is close.

Comment: Yes I mean the UISearchBar. Difine your UISearchBar IBOutLet in you interface h file.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to type: @synthesize searchBar; in my .m file. Now it works. Thanks :D

Comment: You can choose this as an answer if it solved. It will help other to find out the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   [yourTextField1 resignFirstResponder];
   [yourTextField2 resignFirstResponder];
   [yourTextField3 resignFirstResponder];
   [yourSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
   //etc
}
```

But probably you need to check where are you touching at since you don't want to hide the keyboard if you're touching on a text input or search box.

Comment: Tried this also a couple of times. I get the following error: Unkown receiver 'searchBar' did you mean UIDearchBar?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
  [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: I don't get any errors, but it don't work either. Happens nothing. Thanks anyway!

Comment: if you are using scrollview inside view then it won't work otherwise it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to dismiss your keyboard.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (void) dismissKeyboard {
     [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```