# Hide the keyboard for UITextField in the same UIViewController with UISearchbarDisplayController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, keyboard, uitextfield, uisearchdisplaycontroller

How can I hide the keyboard only for specific UITextFields?
I have a lot of UITextField in a View Controller, which has also a SearchbarDisplayController.
I tried to use [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306240/iphone-dismiss-keyboard-when-touching-outside-of-textfield) but it blocks the UISearchbarDisplayController's job.

Thank you.

**For more detail:**

For example I have 3 UITextFields and a searchbar display controller. If there is only UITextFields , while tapping out ofthe keyboard, the keyboard successfully disappear. But when I touch the searchbar, you know the keyboard is open and I enter some text to searchbar. So it gives me some results in searchresultstable of the searchbar. But I can't select any row from searchresultstable. Because the disapper keyboard blocks it.

Comment: please give more details. what you want is to remove the keyboard when the user taps out of the textfield, but only for certain textfields?

Comment: Sorry for the late respond. I add more detail about my problem.

Comment: when you touch the searchbar, the keyboard don't have the search button?

Comment: It searchs automatically with every word that I enter. I followed this tutorial for the searchbar.http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.com/2012/12/table-search-display-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that in this tutorial this method has not been implemented, try to add it

```
 -(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

   [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

Comment: I recreate everything and worked now :/ I still don't know why resighFirstResponder didn't work. Thank you.