# UITextfield inside UITableViewCells - dismiss keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a couple of `UITextfields` in each table cell. By hitting the "Done" button or touching outside the keyboard, the keyboard should be dismissed.

My problem: the `textFieldShouldEndEditing` method is only called when I tap another textfield and the keyboard won't be dismissed.
I think i've implemented the necessary parts (Delegate and protocol methods).

Does anyone know what I'm missing here....?

Here is the code (the relevant part):

```
class myVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate  {...
```

This is the cell setup...

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let tcell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "tbCell")

    let textfield: UITextField = UITextField(frame:...

    switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0: ...
    case 1: 
            textfield.text = section2[indexPath.row]
            tcell.addSubview(textfield)
            textfield.delegate = self
            return tcell
```

and this the protocol method:

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        print("method is called")
        return true
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: you can use textfieldshouldReturn delegate method and write in it textfield.resignFirstRsponder and return true

Comment: You haven't implemented any methods that would dismiss the keyboard, so of course it's not being called. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306240/iphone-dismiss-keyboard-when-touching-outside-of-uitextfield

Comment: @Rajan: Thank you, it works! However, i don't understand the difference to textFieldShouldEndEditing (with resignFirstResponder). Obviously this is what people suggests in a lot of answers around here and should have the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you try textFieldShouldReturn delegate of UITextfield.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return NO;}
```

Answer (score 6):

I am giving this answer in Objective-C because I don't use Swift

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
```

when you will scroll your tableview, and:

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
```

when you will touch outside textfield.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4.0**

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```

or

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
```