# Deselect UITextField when clicking outside

Tags: ios, swift

This could be a dumb question but how can I get out of a selected UITextField if I click anywhere on the screen? I need this in Swift, not Obj-c please. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iphone, dismiss keyboard when touching outside of UITextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306240/iphone-dismiss-keyboard-when-touching-outside-of-uitextfield)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the end editing as true.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){
    view.endEditing(true)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can do like this

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,
withEvent event: UIEvent?) { yourTextfield.resignFirstResponder()}
```

in your view controller