# detect if user touch outside keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, swift4

I implemented this function to detect touches outside keyboard and hide the keyboard

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
```

but how can I do callback when a user touches outside the keyboard? I want another action to happen. I don't want only the keyboard to be hidden.I want to do other function including hiding keyboard everytime the keyboard is hidden I wa=ish to have more actions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iphone, dismiss keyboard when touching outside of UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306240/iphone-dismiss-keyboard-when-touching-outside-of-uitextfield)

Comment: I want to do other function including hiding keyboard everytime the keyboard is hidden I wish to have more actions.

Answer (score 1):

It's super easy. just need to create a function inside the viewcontroller that you want to call and add UIViewController.dismissKeyboard() in it

```
@objc func dismissKeyboardAndOtherStuff(){
 UIViewController.dismissKeyboard()
 // do other stuff
```

}

in you extension change the selector to reflect your new function

```
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboardAndOtherStuff))
```

Comment: I did this but the other stuff will be executed once.

Comment: Will be executed once every time you tap outside. Your wording is ambiguous explain what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I usually create an extension for this case:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboard() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Basically you add a gesture to the view

and you can call it from any ViewController like this:

```
hideKeyboard()
```

Comment: thank you but I want to do other function including hiding keyboard everytime the keyboard is hidden I wish to have more actions.

Comment: You can execute other action inside dismissKeyboard()